# Problem with using a C++ object defined in another file

Tags: c++, class, linker

In my `main.cpp` I have this:

```cpp
#include "main.h"
int main(){
...
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
if (initProg(gWindow, gRenderer) != 0){
    return 1;
}
atexit(SDL_Quit);

Player mainPlayer(gRenderer);
...
}
```

Where Player is a class defined on `player.h` which is included on `main.h`, which looks like this:

```cpp
...
#include "player.h"
...
extern Player mainPlayer;
...
void handlePlayerInput(SDL_Event event);
...
```

Now later in the code, I need to call `handlePlayerInput()` which I have placed in the `input.cpp` file to organize my code. I am having trouble in accessing the `mainPlayer` object however as the following code

```cpp
#include "main.h"
...
    case SDLK_d:
        mainPlayer.movePlayer(Vector2(1, 0));
        break;
...
```

returns:

```
undefined reference to 'mainPlayer'
collect2: error: ld return 1 exit status
```

I am using CMake to compile all my code where I add all my game-related source files (main.cpp, player.cpp, input.cpp, etc) to a library and link that library when compiling the executable with the rest of the non-game-related code.

Comment: Do you declare mainPlayer variable in main.cpp as a global variable? I.e is it outside any functions?

Comment: mainPlayer in main.h takes the argument ...
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/cpp-errors/

Comment: @Ian4264, I declare it as `extern` in main.h and define it in the `main()` function, as I need to pass it the gRenderer pointer.

Comment: You need to define it at global scope to make it available to other modules.